# Check connectivity between DR and PROD cassandra Servers

Tags: cassandra, timeout, production, connectivity, disaster-recovery

I am using ncat/nc command to check connectivity here but i am not sure which port number i should be using, Can anyone suggest?

```
Synatx : nc -vz $HOSTNAME $PORT
> ncat -vz cassandra101.abc.com 9160
Output:
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out.
```

i am getting Connection timeout with all ports 7000,7001, 7199,9042 etc..
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Cassandra disables communication on 9160 by default as of 3.x.  If you can't confirm communications on any of the ports above, then I would start checking firewall/security group definitions.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron i will check on them, but what should i be checking in the firewall/security group definitions ?

Comment: Check `iptables` and see if there are any rules defined to deny communications between the instances.  If you are on AWS, make sure your instances are in the same security group.  If you are on bare metal, talk to you hardware team and see if they know why those two instances cannot communicate.